# Getting Null Pointer Exception while Testing?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I have below method which returns url, but when i try to create unit test for this method, i am getting null pointer exception because of getting uri is null, How can i handle these scenarios, How can i mock Uri.Builder in this. Please help me find out solution.

```
public String getbuildurl(String endPoint, Map<String, String> pathParams, Map<String, String> queryParams) {

    if(pathParams != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : pathParams.entrySet()) {
            endPoint = endPoint.replaceAll("<" + entry.getKey() + ">", entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    Uri.Builder uri = new Uri.Builder();
    uri.appendEncodedPath(endPoint);

    if(queryParams != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
            uri.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    String url = uri.build().toString();
    if(url.startsWith("/"))
        url = uri.build().toString().substring(1);
    return url;

}
```

I am doing in this way to test this:-

```
@Test
public void urlBuildTest() {

    Map<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
    queryParams.put("KEY1","value");
    queryParams.put("KEY2","value1");

    Map<String, String> pathParams = new HashMap<>();
    pathParams.put("Key",value);
    String constructedEndPoint = URLBuilder.getbuildurl(endpoints, pathParams, queryParams);

    Assert.assertNotNull(constructedEndPoint);
}
```

Comment: What line throws the exception?

Comment: Could you show where you initialize endpoints?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson   String url = uri.build().toString(); this line showing exception because uri is null

Comment: endpoints is good no problem in end point, initialized globally

Comment: pathParams.put("Key",value);

String constructedEndPoint = URLBuilder.getbuildurl(endpoints, pathParams, queryParams);


Please share "value" and "endpoints" that are used here

Comment: No it must be the result of `build()` that is nil otherwise you would have gotten the exception earlier when appending the parameters